# How can I return a multidimensional array as a collection of parameters for a JUnit test?

Tags: java, collections, multidimensional-array, junit, parameterized

I'm fairly new to Java, and I'm certainly in over my head.  Okay, disclaimer aside, here's my story:

I have a big list of video filenames and complementary strings called reference ID's in an XML file.  The XML looks like this:

```
<testdata>
  <testcase displayName="video1" refId="vid1xxyyzz" />
  <testcase displayName="video2" refId="vid2aabbcc" />
  .
  .
  <testcase displayName="video499" refId="vid499ffoooo" />
</testdata>
```

I've converted the XML schema into a class using XMLBeans and I'm able to import the data into a couple of arrays using the method documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arraySetGet.html

```
// File import:
    File refIdFile = new File("C:\testdata.xml");
    DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc = DisplayNameReferenceIdDocument.Factory.parse(refIdFile);
    displayNameReferenceId = DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc.getDisplayNameReferenceId();
    tests = displayNameReferenceId.getTestcaseArray();

// Multi-dimensional array get/set:
    matrix = Array.newInstance(String.class, 2, tests.length);
    Object row0 = Array.get(matrix, 0);
    Object row1 = Array.get(matrix, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++){
        displayName = tests[i].getDisplayName();
        refId = tests[i].getRefId();
        Array.set(row0, i, displayName);
        Array.set(row1, i, refId);
    }
```

That's all happening in a `@Parameterized` method in my test class, which must return a collection.  Here's the whole thing, zoomed out:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ValidateDisplayNameReferenceIdTest {

static DisplayNameReferenceIdDocument DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc;
static DisplayNameReferenceId displayNameReferenceId;
static DisplayNameReferenceId.Test[] tests;
static String displayName;
static String refId;
static Object matrix;

@Parameterized.Parameters(name="{index}: {0}")
public static Collection<Object> getTestParameters() throws IOException, XmlException {
    File refIdFile = new File("C:\testdata.xml");

    DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc = DisplayNameReferenceIdDocument.Factory.parse(refIdFile);
    displayNameReferenceId = DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc.getDisplayNameReferenceId();
    tests = displayNameReferenceId.getTestArray();
    matrix = Array.newInstance(String.class, 2, tests.length);
    Object row0 = Array.get(matrix, 0);
    Object row1 = Array.get(matrix, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++){
        displayName = tests[i].getDisplayName();
        refId = tests[i].getRefId();
        Array.set(row0, i, displayName);
        Array.set(row1, i, refId);
    }
    System.out.println("tweet");
    return Arrays.asList(matrix);  // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS!
}


private String displayNameInput;
private String refIdExpected;

public ValidateDisplayNameReferenceIdTest(String input, String expected ) {
    displayNameInput = input;
    refIdExpected = expected;
}

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    // send the API URL with 'displayNameInput', validate result for 'refIdExpected'
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url1 + displayNameInput + url2 + token).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(response, writer);
    String responseString = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(responseString);
    //Here goes something like assert(response.contains(refIdExpected));

    }
}
```

When I run this as is I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`.

I think I might be over-complicating the data structure, but now that it's built that way and seems to be successfully pulling in the data elements, I don't know how else to rebuild.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the whole gory exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(Parameterized.java:186)
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTest(Parameterized.java:181)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: where / how is matrix defined? Also does the exception have any more information?

Comment: I'll add it above.  Right at the start of the class it's defined as `static Object matrix;`  Exception added as well.

Comment: Hmm, question, which line is line 186?

Comment: That's weird.  I dig down to `Parameterized.class` and it only goes to line 65.  Let me see if my JUnit libraries are current...

Comment: Here we go, `Parameterized.class` from 185..187: `private Object createTestUsingConstructorInjection() throws Exception {return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance(fParameters);}`

Comment: This all seems very complicated to just get some data into the test class for the tests.
Why not just use a set up method with an `@Before` annotation that then populates a `Map<String, String>`?
If your concern is that you only want to do the reading and populating once, then have an `if(map.isEmpty())` check before reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is defined like this:

```
static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

It takes a variable-length parameter list.  When you call a method like this, the program actually builds an array to pass to the method--*unless* you call it with one argument and the argument is already an array.  In that case, it will pass the array you've already built.

The problem here is that if you've defined `matrix` as an `Object`, the compiler won't see that as an array.  So it constructs a one-element array with `matrix` as the element.  Ultimately this messes up the JUnit code.

To use `asList`, you'll need to make sure that the parameter has an actual array type (at compile time).  However, I'm not sure just what will work.  You want something like this:

```
return Arrays.asList((Object[][])matrix);
```

but I have a feeling the type cast will fail at run time.  You may need to declare `matrix` as

```
Object[][] matrix;
```

and then instead of

```
matrix = Array.newInstance(String.class, 2, tests.length);
```

say

```
matrix = new Object[2][tests.length];
```

(I don't see any benefit to using `Array.newInstance` here anyway, instead of using just a regular `new`.)

Comment: That would clear up the data structure, but then how would I return that Object as a collection?

Comment: If you declare `Object[][] matrix;`, then `Arrays.asList(matrix)` should work.  It will return an `ArrayList` where each element is a 2-element `Object[]` array.

Comment: Actually, the examples in the JUnit Wiki show the `@Parameters` function being declared like `public static Collection<Object[]> data()`, i.e. with `[]` after `Object`.  You may need to fix the  `getTestParameters` declaration like that.

Comment: This seems to be the right track, however now I'm seeing in the JUnit results that the first of each row is being treated as its own single parameter, and each returns `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`.  I'll keep hacking away at it.  Thanks!

Comment: @kyoob I'd consider trying to rewrite this without the `Array` class.  `Array` is part of Java's "reflection" feature, and reflection is a feature that can be useful for specialized purposes, but not to accomplish something "normal".  (I very rarely use it.)  If you can do what you need to do using normal array indexing, you should do that; using `Array` unnecessarily could possibly cause problems, by letting you do something that you shouldn't be doing and that won't be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the JUnit `@Parameters` method needs to return a List of Object arrays and you're passing it a List of String Arrays. Since a two dimensional array is basically just an array of arrays, passing your twodimensional String array (`String[][]`) into Arrays.asList() returns a `List<String[]>`, a list of String arrays.

As you set it up though, it's really easy to fix, just change the `String.class` argument you pass to your Array constructor to `Object.class` and you should have functioning tests.

Comment: Just tried this, and it's a no-go.  I switched that argument so it's like `matrix = Array.newInstance(Object.class, 2, tests.length);` and I get the same error in the same place.  One thing that did change when I tried this was the JUnit result before it croaked.  Used to look like `test[0: [Ljava.lang.String;@5678b14]`, now looks like `test[0: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4567b14]`

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting already that what I though initially was your problem wasn't it after all, so as per my comment on the question, which line is 186?

Comment: Here it is: `return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance(fParameters);`

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't edit @ajb's answer and subsequent comments I'll put what finally worked here, in its own answer.

As suggested, I'd tried declaring `matrix` as an `Object[][]` but left the rest of the expression and `for` loop alone, and it still didn't work.  It was the `newInstance` way of setting up my array of arrays which was getting me into trouble.  In the end I took that out and replaced the pertinent block with this:

```
    //Same as before from XMLBeans methods:
    DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc = DisplayNameReferenceIdDocument.Factory.parse(refIdFile);
    displayNameReferenceId = DisplayNameReferenceIdDoc.getDisplayNameReferenceId();
    tests = displayNameReferenceId.getTestcaseArray();

    //new, simpler Object setup strategy:
    int i;
    Object[][] matrix = new Object[tests.length][2];
    for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        matrix[i][0] = tests[i].getDisplayName();
        matrix[i][1] = tests[i].getRefId();
    };
    return Arrays.asList(matrix);
```

The `@Parameterized` test runner sent the value pairs to my test constructor as expected and the class began happily making web service calls as instructed by my `@Test` block.

In a perfect world the `XMLBeans` package itself would send back multidimensional arrays for complex line items so the user wouldn't have to do this wrangling.